# Determine the Norm of the linear functional $I_\mu(f)=\int_X f\,d\mu$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ be a (finite) complex Radon measure on $X$. Since we have
$$\left|\int_X f\,d\mu\right|\leq \int_X |f|\,d|\mu|\leq \|f\|_\infty |\mu|(X).$$
for all $f\in C_c(X\to\mathbf{C})$, here $\|f\|_\infty:=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$. The linear functional $I_\mu:C_c(X\to \mathbf{C})\to \mathbf{C}$ defined by $I_\mu(f):=\int_X f\,d\mu$ is bounded and has operator norm at most $|\mu|(X)$, here we give $C_c(X\to\mathbf{C})$ the supremum norm. How to show that $I_\mu$ is actually has operator norm $|\mu|(X)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use $\|\mu\|$ for $\lvert \mu\rvert(X)$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose a finite partition $\{E_1,\ldots, E_n\}$ of $X$ such that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \lvert \mu(E_i)\rvert > \lvert \mu\rvert(X) - \epsilon/2$. Let $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n$ be complex numbers of unit modulus such that $\alpha_i\mu(E_i) = \lvert \mu(E_i)\rvert$, $i = 1,2,\ldots, n$. Let $s := \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i1_{E_i}$. Then $$\left\lvert\int_X s\, d\mu\right\rvert = \left\lvert\sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i\mu(E_i)\right\rvert = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lvert \mu(E_i)\rvert > \|\mu\| - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ By regularity of $\mu$, there exist compact sets $K_1,\ldots, K_n$ and open sets $V_1,\ldots, V_n$ such that $K_i \subset E_i \subset V_i$ and $\lvert\mu\rvert(V_i \setminus K_i) < \epsilon/(2n)$, for $i = 1,2,\ldots, n$. By Urysohn's lemma, there are functions $f_1,\ldots, f_n\in C_c(X\to \bf{R})$ such that for all $i$, $0 \le f_i \le 1$, $f_i = 1$  on $K_i$, and $\operatorname{supp}(f_i) \subset V_i$. Note that for each $i$, $1_{E_i} - f_i$ vanishes outside $V_i\setminus K_i$ and is bounded by $1$ on $V_i\setminus K_i$. Define $f := (1/n)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n\alpha_i \,f_i$. Then $f\in C_c(X\to \bf{C})$, $\lvert f\rvert \le 1$, and

$$\int_X\lvert s - f\rvert\, d\lvert \mu\rvert \le \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\sum_{i = 1}^n  \int_X\lvert 1_{E_i} - f_i\rvert\, d\lvert \mu\rvert \le \sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{V_i \setminus K_i} \lvert 1_{E_i} - f_i\lvert\, d\lvert \mu\rvert \le \sum_{i = 1}^n \lvert \mu\rvert(V_i\setminus K_i) \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Therefore,

\begin{align}\left\lvert \int_X f\, d\mu\right\rvert &\ge \left\lvert \int_X s\, d\mu\right\rvert - \left\lvert \int_X (s - f)\, d\mu\right\rvert
\ge \left\lvert \int_X s\, d\mu\right\rvert - \int_X \lvert s - f\rvert\, d\lvert \mu\rvert
> \left(\|\mu\| - \frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) - \frac{\epsilon}{2}
= \|\mu\| - \epsilon\end{align}
Thus $\|I_\mu\| \ge \lvert I_\mu(f)\rvert > \|\mu\| - \epsilon$. Letting $\epsilon \to 0$, we obtain $\|I_\mu\| \ge \|\mu\|$ and therefore $\|I_\mu\| = \|\mu\|$.

Comment: I have a very similar question about the norm of μ(f)=∫fdμ restricted to the space of continuous functions over K when μ is a probability on a compact Hausdorff space K. To my understanding, if we have a linear operator bounded by a constant C and find an element with norm at most 1 that achieves that bound then equality should hold. The book I've been reading gives a completely different and way more complicated proof of this fact, as if taking $f\equiv 1$ wasn't a correct reasoning. I'm really confused by this.

Comment: Hi @ModestoRosado, taking $f = 1$ would be valid in your case since this $f$ is certainly in $C(K)$.

Comment: Then I just don't get why the book I'm reading resorts to a less general and way more complicated proof. Truth be told, they define the integral as the continuous extension of a linear operator on $\mathcal{A}_{K}$-simple functions (the integral of a simple function is defined in the usual manner) where $\mathcal{A}_{K}$ is the algebra generated by $K$'s topology. But they claim that with this definition, the integral is monotone and satisfies the inequalities $\mid\int fd\mu\mid\leq\int\mid f\mid d\mu\leq\parallel f\parallel_{\infty}$.

Comment: @Modesto are the measures in your text Radon measures or are they more generalized measures (e.g., finitely additive measures)?

Comment: They are finitely additive. But how does that hinder the proof?

Comment: I mean, problems would arise if calculating the integral of $1$ required countable additivity, but since $1$ is simple, then by definition $\int 1d\mu=\mu(K)=1$, since $\mu$ is a probability. Of course, I'm assuming that the integral of a simple function is well-defined in the sense that it doesn't depend on the way we write the function.

Comment: @ModestoRosado I didn't mean to suggest that a generalized measure will hinder the proof. It's just that (depending on how relaxed the conditions on a measure are) more care is taken to define integration. But if it's already shown in your text that the map $f \mapsto \int_K f\, d\mu$ is a linear functional on $C(K)$ bounded by $1$, then it's still appropriate to consider $f = 1$ to show that the norm is $\ge 1$, hence equal to $1$.

Comment: Well, it's strange then. I'll take another look at the text to make sure I'm not making any extra assumptions. I was starting to question basic facts in functional analysis and measure theory, but it looks like I'm not talking nonsense. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the opposite inequality, note that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $|\mu|$. By the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), we have that 
$d\mu=gd|\mu|$. Moreover, it's not difficult to show that $|g(x)|=1$ for all almost every $x\in X$ (see Rudin's *Real and complex analysis* Theorem 6.12). Since $C_c(X\to\mathbf{C})$ is dense in $L^1(X,|\mu|)$, we can find a sequence of continuous compactly supported functions $f_n\in C_c(X\to\mathbf{C})$ such that $f_n\to g$ in $L^1(X,|\mu|$). Let $g_n=\phi(f_n)$ where $\phi:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ is the continous function defined by $\phi(z)=z$ if $|z|\leq 1$ and $|\phi(z)|=z/|z|$ if $|z|\geq 1$. Then $|g_n|\leq 1$ and $g_n\to g$ in $L^1(X,|\mu|)$. Thus
$$\|\mu\|=|\mu(X)|=\int_X \,d|\mu|=\int_X \overline{g}\,d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{g_n}\,d\mu\leq \|I_\mu\|.$$